# Angular 2 cache management best practices

Tags: angular, caching, design-patterns

I am facing issues managing cache efficiently in Angular 2. I use HTTP interceptors for that. The major problem I am facing is data incoherence. Everytime I update an object, I need to loop over cache data to reflect this change to all entities that depends on this change (using complex bug prone logic).

Are their any best practices/guidlines/design patterns to manage cache efficiently in Angular 2 applications ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `BehaviorSubject`, which, [according to the documentation](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#behaviorsubject),

> One of the variants of Subjects is the BehaviorSubject, which has a notion of "the current value". It stores the latest value emitted to its consumers, and whenever a new Observer subscribes, it will immediately receive the "current value" from the BehaviorSubject.

This should update all subscribers without the need of any logic from your side. Is this what you asked, or is it rather a caching issue ?

Comment: this may be one piece for a cleaner solution, but I think caching is so special and reccurent that it should have dedicated complete guidelines to manage it efficiently.

Comment: Well it has, and you've seen it in the interceptors ! Now it's up to you to handle your components updates, and I think BehaviorSubject is a good approach. But I see your point, and I agree with it : it should be on Angular's website ! Like a lot of documentation there, it's either missing, or outdated, and it's unfortunate.